# What happened to Brenda?

Tags: plot-explanation, rules-of-engagement

In the TV series [Rules of Engagement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rules_of_Engagement_%28TV_series%29), Brenda (Sara Rue) was going have Audrey and Jeff's baby. Now her character seems to be gone from the plot. Did they just drop the plot point and move on without Sara Rue, or did I miss the episode that explains her absence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Sara Rue](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0749081/) was again in the most current episode broadcast May 10,2012, "Goodbye Dolly", where she is in the later stage of pregnancy for Jeff and Audrey's child. I'm guessing that the baby will be the final act of this series, which is, as of today (May 13, 2012), still not renewed for a new season, though most other shows on CBS have had a decision.
UPDATE (May 13, 2012 afternoon): CBS just now revealed its cancellation plans for all remaining shows EXCEPT Rules of Engagement, leading me now to think it may survive to next season, and the Baby will be a key plot driver.